# I'd like to build a site map generator in a single line of bash code

Tags: javascript, xml, bash, sitemap

My static site generator has a `/pages` directory with a bunch of source files. The names of those source files need to be prepended with my website URL, and then concatenated into a file (Either .txt or .xml).

Here's what I have so far:

`find ./pages -name '*.js' \( -exec echo "$FILE"/{} \; -o -print \)`

This command prints the names of the files with the extra pages directory up front like this:

```
/pages/index.js
/pages/articles/article-title.js
/pages/about/index.js
/pages/about/team.js
...
```

I'm not fantastic with bash. How do I edit each line to include `https://www.example.com` in front of each line, removing `/pages`?

Also, I'll need to remove the word index anywhere it appears. `/pages/about/index.js` should become `https://www.example.com/about` for example, and `/pages/about/team.js` should become `https://www.example.com/about/team`

**Bonus**

A list of URLs in a .txt file is an acceptable sitemap and I'm happy with that, but if we want to go beyond, we can produce an XML file that has last modified dates.

`date -r pages/about.js +"%Y-%m-%d" | tee test.xml` This command writes the correct modified date, but I'd have to get it in this final format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.example.com</loc>
    <lastmod>2023-03-01</lastmod>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.example.com/about</loc>
    <lastmod>2023-03-12</lastmod>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: I am asking for help with code, not recommendations. Reopen my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```bash
> find ./pages -name '*.js' \( -exec echo "$FILE"/{} \; -o -print \)
> ```
>
> This command prints the names of the files with the extra pages > directory up front like this:
>
> ```bash
> /pages/index.js
> /pages/articles/article-title.js
> /pages/about/index.js
> /pages/about/team.js
> ...
> ```

No, it doesn't.  Provided that variable `FILE` has not been set, that command will produce output lines of this form:

```
/./pages/index.js
```

If `FILE` *had* been set to a non-null string, then the output would differ even more from what you say.  To produce output in the form you show, I suppose that you were actually running this similar command:

```bash
find pages -name '*.js' \( -exec echo "$FILE"/{} \; -o -print \)
```

And given that the `$FILE` part is doing nothing, and the `-o -print` is relevant only in the unlikely event that `echo` returns a failure status, a simpler way to achieve the same thing would be

```bash
find pages -name '*.js' -exec echo /{} \;
```

Since you want to modify the beginnings of the output lines, however, it's not particularly useful to prepend a slash, and since `-print` is the default, I would start with just

```bash
find pages -name '*.js'
```

Then, `sed` is one of the typical tools for modifying lines of a file.  It looks like you want something along these lines to substitute the leading `pages` of each result line with the first part of the corresponding URL:

```bash
find pages -name '*.js' | sed 's|^pages|https://www.example.com|'
```

There's no one-liner for producing the XML format you describe using common shell utilities.  It would be possible to write a script to generate that, but I leave it as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks, John! This is helpful. Learning bash has been a bit of a journey : )